# Why is it 'Are you studying every night?' But 'Do you study every night?'

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, present-continuous

I know 'Are you studying every night?' is present continuous and I think 'Do you study every night?' is not, but why not? Why does this sentence work as both present simple and continuous when it's still an ongoing action?

Answer (score 1):

You can say either, but with somewhat different effect.

***Do you study every night?***

The present simple can be used to express habitual action, meaning the above question asks if nightly studies are something you habitually do.

***Are you studying every night?***

The present continuous expresses action that is ongoing, meaning the above question asks if nightly studies are ongoing for you.

The nuance between using the present simple and the present continuous lies in the fact that the present simple's use to express habitual action conveys the action as *continual*, not *continuous*, "continual" being intermittent and recurring and "continuous" being steady and ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

> Are you studying every night?

is more likely in real life. Present continuous can be used for habitual actions during a period of time that is not finished.

> The present continuous is used to express repeated or habitual actions in the present that are temporary and may or may not actually be happening at the time of speaking:
>
> - Lucy ***is taking*** piano lessons *these days*. ([grammaring](https://www.grammaring.com/present-continuous-for-temporary-habitual-actions-in-the-present))

So you can say:

> Are you studying every night *this week/month/to prepare for this exam*?

---

As for

> Do you study every night?

I think it is less likely that a person study every night indefinitely, so the present continuous would be more accurate.